# NSPredicate array for NSCompoundPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

Please Help me, i want to  make a coredata get function in Swift 2.2 NSPredicate array for NSCompoundPredicate

```
public func loadData(entityName: String, filters: [String: String] = [:], dataFault: Bool = true) -> [NSManagedObject] {
    var listItems: [NSManagedObject]?
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.managedObjectContext {
        let fetchRequist = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        if (filters.count > 0) {
            var predicte: [NSPredicate]
            for (key, value) in filters {
                let p1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, value as NSObject)
                predicte.appendContentsOf(p1)
            }
            fetchRequist.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicte)
        }
        fetchRequist.returnsObjectsAsFaults = dataFault
        do{
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequist)
            listItems = results as? [NSManagedObject]
        }
        catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

    }
    else{
        print("context Error")
    }
    return listItems!

}
```

There show error on predicte.appendContentsOf(p1)

Comment: Give details of the error and what you expect to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `p1` is not a CollectionType, so you need to use `append`, not `appendContentsOf`:

```
                predicte.append(p1)
```

Also, you need to initialize your `predicte` appropriately:

```
            var predicte: [NSPredicate] = []
```

Comment: Thanks , it's work. and please tell me that is good way to code or not

Comment: @AyonSaha, sorry, but I'm not sure if my way of using Core Data is a good way or not. I'm learning many things from the web resources, including the classic threads of Stack Overflow. Keep watch on them.

Comment: i'm not talking about your solution, i'm talking about my total function and my way coding, or i'm going right way or not

Comment: @AyonSaha, I mean, if I knew what's good, I could have improved my apps  and said mine's good.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again for your solution